# What does this parentheses notation mean, $i = 1(1)k$?

Tags: notation, random-matrices

I'm reading [these lecture notes](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/mmahoney/cs369m/Lectures/lecture1.pdf). On page 3, he uses the notation $i = 1(1)k$. What does this mean?

Comment: Going up in steps of $1$ ?